# How to measure two different codes

Tags: c#

How do I compare the `.equals("")` and `.IsNullOrEmpty`? I want to know which of the two is faster. I've heard of using ticks but not yet familiar on how to code this.

Comment: This is considered a premature optimization any difference will be so trivial.

Comment: you mean using `Stopwatch` to measure it ?

Comment: Please give some more details of what kind of metrics you are looking for and the possibly the use case.

Comment: What will I put inside the for loop?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`StopWatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) class to measure execution time of the code. Start the stopwatch, run a few thousand iterations, stop it and look at the elapsed time. Do the same for the other implementation. Also make sure you try a few edge cases, like comparing `null` or empty strings or even very long strings. Just comparing `"foo"` a dozen times to `""` doesn't prove anything.

Note though that the answer is very likely completely irrelevant to your problem. Your time is better spent improving other parts of your code.

Comment: There is such a thing as too much information but there is never such a thing as too much knowledge.

Comment: My point isn't that knowledge in general is useless. It's just that this particular case of knowledge is useless in 99.9999 % of all cases and the single one case where it matters is the point where you can justify spending time on micro-benchmarking `Equals` vs. `IsNullOrEmpty`. In all other cases it's pointless and a profiler could show you the actual hotspots of your application.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are isNullOrEmpty is faster since it's special purpose.  As others who have commented have pointed out however, this is an exceedingly trivial optimization.

Comment: Checking a strings length for 0 is much faster than comparing it to the empty string, at least in all of the benchmarks I've done (never in C#, but in other C family languages).  It's possible that it falls back on the existing equals implementation.  In general however, as my grandpappy always said, if you're going to bother reinventing the wheel, you might as well do it better.

Answer (score 1):

Use `StopWatch` in follwing way:

```
// Create new stopwatch
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

// Begin timing
stopwatch.Start();

// Do something here

// Stop timing
stopwatch.Stop();
```

Answer (score 1):

As said by other, this is premature optimization and probably not worth of your time. But, for the sake of the answer, this is how you can do it:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication1 {   
    class Program {   
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            int COUNT = 1000000000;
            String str = "Something";

            Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            sw.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {
                if (str.Equals("")) {
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedTicks);

            sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            sw.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(str)) {
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(sw.ElapsedTicks);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The output is for me:

```
21426768  // Equals("")
12365410  // IsNullOrEmpty() <-- faster
```

Please not that `str.Equals("")` and `String.IsNullOrEmpty(str)` won't give you the same result. Obviously, the first one will raise a NullReferenceException is `str` is null.